# Convert NSData to PEM to Sign Certificate in Node.js

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, security, csr

I am creating a CSR using this library on iOS and then encoding it as Base 64. 
https://github.com/ateska/ios-csr

The library creates the CSR as NS Data on iOS.

I am able to send this data to my Node.JS server. I want to convert this to a PEM so that I can sign this CSR using the server's private key. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @MehtaiPhoneApps, we was talking about this subject last week. I guess you have a solution, but if not I provide you an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SCCCSR from ios-csr library you will have a certificate request in PKCS#10 format, encoded in binary

```
let certificateRequest = sccsr.build(publicKey, privateKey: privateKey)
```

A PEM format requires a conversion to Base64 and around with the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----` headers

```
let certificateRequestB64 = certificateRequest.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions())
let certificateRequestPEM =
        "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\\n" + certificateRequestB64 + "\\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\\n"
```